# Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, template, custom

path: `app\code\local\Bhtech\Designer`
inside this folder all other folder Block, Controller

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Bhtech_Designer>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bhtech_Designer>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Bhtech_Designer</module>
                 <frontName>designer</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
       <layout>
            <updates>
                <bhtech_designer>
                    <file>bhtech_designer.xml</file>
                </bhtech_designer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <bhtech_designer>
                <class>Bhtech_Designer_Block</class>
            </bhtech_designer>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

indexController.php

```
<?php
class Bhtech_Designer_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    protected function _initAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
        return $this;
    }
    public function indexAction()
    {
         $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('bhtech/designer');
         $block->setTemplate('designer/designer.phtml');
         echo $block->toHtml(); 
        //Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());

    }  
}
```

Block
designer.php

```
<?php
class Bhtech_Designer_Block_Designer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    // Methods (optional)
}
?>
```

designer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- Root node for Magento layout configuration -->
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!--Page handle -->
    <designer_index_view>
        <!-- reference tag specifies the block where we a going to add child block -->
        <reference name="content">
            <!-- Our page content block -->
            <block type="bhtech/designer" name="designer" template="design.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </designer_index_view>
</layout>
```

path: app\design\frontend\bhtech\designer
inside this folder layout and template folders are placed

layout.xml

```
<block type="bhtech/designer" template="bhtech/designer.phtml">
    <action method="setData">
        <key>area</key>
        <value>frontend</value>
    </action>
</block>
```

but I still getting error my magento version 1.9
please help me out if there any details document or example of this please give me that. I'm just trying to load a complete new template for a page.

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.xml` your blocks name is not properly declared, you need to replace:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <bhtech_designer>
            <class>Bhtech_Designer_Block</class>
        </bhtech_designer>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

With:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <bhtech>
            <class>Bhtech_Designer_Block</class>
        </bhtech>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

Comment: @Dhiman feel free to mark your question as answered so it will benefit for others